# How to set height of ListBox to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Html ListBox:

```
 <select id="targetField" multiple="multiple" name="D1" style="width:200px;">
              <option>INDIA</option>
              <option>USA</option>
              <option>UK</option>
              <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
              <option>RUSSIA</option>
              <option>FRANCE</option>
              <option>HOLLAND</option>
 </select>
```

I need to set the height of this to auto i.e I do not want scrollbar to appear.

I tried `Height:auto;` But it is not working in IE.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the [`size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select) to the number of items, like this:

```
<select id="targetField" multiple name="D1" style="width:200px;" size="7">
```

If you need to do it programmatically, you can set all `<select>` elements to their option length, like this:

```
$("select").attr("size", function() { return this.options.length; });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7cZrH/).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it using 'line-height' eighter and putting values to 'height'.

```
<select id="targetField" multiple="multiple" name="D1" style="width:200px; line-height:27px; float:left; height:130px;">
              <option>INDIA</option>
              <option>USA</option>
              <option>UK</option>
              <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
              <option>RUSSIA</option>
              <option>FRANCE</option>
              <option>HOLLAND</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the size attribute equal to the number of items(options).

```
var select = $('#targetField');
select.attr('size', select[0].options.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `height:100%`. It is working in ie6